# Video.js this.tech is undefined IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, video.js

I am getting script errors only with IE8/IE7 with videoJS 4.1x and 4.2x.

**line 3357 (in current 4.2.1):**

```
this.tech.one('mousemove', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

The animations work anyway, but this error makes it hard to see any other errors we are getting when something else is messed up.

Comment: I am not the only person that has complained about this and there is nothing in the documentation to explain this. So why not answer this. Why does the code throw an error repeatedly, messing up the debugger, rather than do this properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a proper solution, but in the meanwhile you can prevent these errors from appearing by creating a dummy tech object when it is undefined.

```
var player = videojs(
    // ...
);

if (!player.tech) {
    player.tech = {
        one: function () {},
        ready: function () {}
    };
}
```

To clarify: in my case, errors related to `this.tech` appeared in browsers which don't have Flash installed while it is the only possibility for them (IE8 and below). So I assume tech is basically empty because nothing is available.